Google Sheets convert /Date(1714867200000)/ ...to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
In the event this question has (indeed) been asked before ...my apologies (still learning how to use StackOverFlow)
Please let me know if there's a Google/Spreadsheet "Function" that will provide a DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS (readable) "Date" value into Column "B"?
I think the format is Json (not sure) ...I've copied the date column into a "forum friendly" Google Sheet
Link to Google Sheet with Date "Column"


Does this answer your question? Converting unix time into date-time via excel


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,epochtodate(--regexextract(Σ,"\d{10}")))))



format the column to required date format accordingly


WOW @rockinfreakshow, that's all my mind is able to say.   Such a simple formula that doesn't require dividing or left/right functions - THANK YOU.
